# ListView rows getting clipped

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

*Newbie Alert*

I'm populating my ListView with rows that are using ConstraintLayout. I thought that the row heights would be adjusted automatically based on the content, however that doesn't seem to be happening. Should it?

My Fragment code:

```
public class ConversationListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(Conversation conversation);
    }

    OnItemSelectedListener selectionListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        Messaging controller = MessagingFactory.getInstance().getController();

        Conversation[] conversations = controller.amsConversations.getActiveConversations();
        setListAdapter(new ConversationListAdapter(getActivity(), conversations));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            selectionListener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Conversation conversation = (Conversation) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        selectionListener.onItemSelected(conversation);
    }
}
```

My adapter getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lpmessaging_ui_conversation_list_entry, parent, false);
        convertView.setMinimumHeight(105); // not helping

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.remoteName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.conversation_list_remote_name);
        viewHolder.lastMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.conversation_list_last_message);
        viewHolder.unreadCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.conversation_list_unread_counter);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // set textView text here

    return convertView;
}
```

My layout XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_list_remote_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Brand Name"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="24dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="272dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_list_last_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Last Message"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/conversation_list_remote_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conversation_list_unread_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lpinfra_ui_scroll_down_unread_counter_shape"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/scroll_down_indicator_unread_counter_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/regular_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/verticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="45dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

I tried to setMinimumHeight on the inflated view, but is that in SP or pixels or points or what? I tried values of 35 and 105, but it didn't change anything.

How do I get my ListView rows to size properly?

Comment: It looks like it's due to the padding.  Have you tried using margins instead?  Also, you should probably not use match_parent for the height in list cells for vertical scrolling.

Comment: @Submersed, I removed the top/bottom padding from the ConstraintLayout and it didn't help. Just removed the white space and row heights were then less showing the text clipped and butted up to the top and bottom.

Comment: try putting everything into a linear/relative layout with match parent height

Comment: @DroiDev I originally had horizontal linear layout with sub-linear vertical layout for the text items and I had issues with that too. That's why I tried this. It actually shows more than the linear layouts did.

Comment: can you post the code for your ListView? where you implement the list. (not the adapter class)

Comment: where are you initializing your listview? for my list view I do something like AdapterClass adapter = new AdaptorClass(listView.getContext(), list); listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: what does this layout look like? lpmessaging_ui_conversation_list_entry --> does it just have a <ListView>?

Comment: also, fragments should use a onCreateView to get the view of thefragments layout.

Comment: @DroiDev ListFragment has a default ListView provided. You'll note that the last line in the onCreate method of the fragment sets the adapter. To me, nothing in this is related to the ListView row height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the iOS constraint system, you want constraints from the top of the container view down to the bottom. None of the objects in the ConstraintLayout have constraints to the top or bottom of the parent.

Add a constraint from the top TextView to the parent and a constraint from the bottom TextView to the parent and this will let android size the row properly.

Comment: looks like you do? app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf

Comment: @DroiDev, the target of that constraint is a guideline. If you look carefully, you'll see no TextView in the posted question has a constraint with the top/bottom target of the parent.